# Getting two new tabs on one click of button in tab control

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello everyone I am trying to add  new tab in in my winform I am using the following code in my form. But when I click on the button its add two tabs instead of one tab 
Please review my code where I am going wrong

```
 private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage tab = new TabPage("New Tab");
            tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1,tab);
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because you assign to tabControl1.Selected property the newly created page. The assignment raises again the SelectedIndexChanged and you add another tabpage.

You could prevent this recursion adding a global class level variable to your form and using it as a semaphore before entering your adding page code

```
private bool addingPage = false;

....


 private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(!addingPage)
    {
        addingPage = true;
        TabPage tab = new TabPage("New Tab");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1,tab);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
        addingPage = false;
    }
 }
```